# How to pass multiple parameters gained from a mysql table in a java servlet form

Tags: java, servlets

This is my first time using Java servlets and I'm wanting to make a small picture gallery site. At the moment i'm having issues with how i'm passing parameters. Basically the input hidden field is passing all the parameters, and in the second and last servlet it's always coming up with the same folder name so it can never find different pictures in different folders.

I cannot work out how to fetch something from a mysql table that should be unique for each radio button, and then pass this information to the next servlet. Since it's passing ever folder category at the moment and the only folder i can actually use is the first folder in the category table.

THis is what is in my url for the second servlet

```
http://localhost:8080/techfore/SelectingPage?ShortName=AntShowcase&CategoryNo=3&ShortName=UMLDiagrams&ShortName=WildArt&ShortName=Traditional&ShortName=DreamweaverImages&ShortName=WindowsWallpaper
```

This is whats in my url in the last servlet

```
http://localhost:8080/techfore/PicturePage?PictureName=Redmoondesert.jpg&ShortName=AntShowcase
```

Database tablets

```
Categories DB
CategoryNo, ShortName, Description, Folder

Pictures DB
PictureNo, CategoryNo, Shortname, Description, FileName
```

I need to present a user with a category selection page which the below servlet tries to do.

```
   Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
   String query;
   ResultSet rs;

   // List the categories
   query = "SELECT ShortName, Folder, CategoryNo FROM Categories ORDER BY CategoryNo";
   rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);


   out.println("Please select a category of pictures to explore:");

   String URL = "http://localhost:8080/techfore/SelectingPage";



   out.println("<form method=\"GET\" action=\"" + URL + "\">");
   while (rs.next()) {

      String shortName = rs.getString("ShortName");
      String folderName = rs.getString("Folder");
      int CategoryNo = rs.getInt("CategoryNo");


      out.println("<input type = \"radio\" name =\"CategoryNo\" value="+CategoryNo+">"+shortName+"");
      out.println("<br>");
      out.println("<input type = \"hidden\" name =\"ShortName\" value="+folderName+">");



   }
   Utilities.oneButtonForm(out, URL, "Let me select a category");
   out.println("</form>");
```

The next servlet should present a list of pictures from that particular category

```
   try {

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String query;
        ResultSet rs;

        query="SELECT Folder FROM Categories WHERE CategoryNo = "+categoryNo+"";

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while(rs.next()) {
            shortName = rs.getString("Folder");
        }

        stmt.close() ;




    }
    catch(SQLException ex) {
        out.println("<P>SQLException: " + ex.getMessage()) ;
     }
    out.println("Folder is:" +shortName);






    try {
       Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
       String query;
       ResultSet rs;




       // List the categories
       query = "SELECT PictureNo, ShortName, Description, FileName FROM Pictures WHERE CategoryNo ="+categoryNo+" ORDER BY PictureNo";

       rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);


       String URL = "http://localhost:8080/techfore/PicturePage/"+shortName+"";





       out.println("<form method=\"GET\" action=\"" + URL+">");

       while (rs.next()) {


          String pictureName = rs.getString("ShortName");
          String fileName = rs.getString("FileName");



          out.println("<input type = \"radio\" name =\"PictureName\" value="+fileName+">"+pictureName+"");
          out.println("<br>");




       }
       out.println("<input type = \"hidden\" name=\"ShortName\" value="+shortName+"");


       Utilities.oneButtonForm(out, URL, "Let me see th");


       out.println("</form>");

      out.println("<form action=\"/http://localhost:8080/techfore/WelcomePage\">" + 
            "    <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Let me choose another category\" />\r\n" + 
            "</form>");



       stmt.close() ;
    }
```

The last servlet should display the picture, which exists on another site (I just need to provide the folder and the filename.

```
out.println("<img src=http://www.uni.site.sc.dk/courses/Pictures/Gallery/"+categoryName+"/"+pictureName+"");

      out.println("<form action=/"+referer+">" + 
            "    <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Let me choose another picture\" />\r\n" + 
            "</form>");


      out.println("<form action=\"/http://localhost:8080/techfore/WelcomePage\">" + 
                "    <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Let me choose another category\" />\r\n" + 
                "</form>");
```

The main issue is the folder is always the same due to how I'm getting it in the first servlet.

Comment: As an aside, this code looks like it allows a [SQL Injection attack](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiRxrTlmtLeAhVB4oMKHTD3CfkQFjAAegQICxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fsql%2Fsql_injection.asp&usg=AOvVaw1S-bwpggsWZe1QUjSOSy4G):

       query = "SELECT PictureNo, ShortName, Description, FileName FROM Pictures WHERE CategoryNo ="+categoryNo+" ORDER BY PictureNo";

Comment: It is good practice to NOT depend on the web browser for as much as possible.  For example, someone might be able to construct a foldername that might leave you open to an attack, or mess up your server.  Using browser tools, it is trivial to mess with POST parameters. 
With that in mind, you should instead take the CategoryNo input in the second servlet, validate it, and use that to look up the FolderName in the database.  This ensures that the end user can't mess around with your data, and also reduces the size of your form, and the attempt to include a hidden element inside a radio.

Comment: Can i run 2 result sets and 2 queries in one servlet?

Comment: Yes, you can run two queries.  For the above scenario, your first query would only typically return zero or one record, which you would use to extract the Folder from.   But now, the third servlet, you need to remember the folder name and the picture name.  Instead, you might just use the PictureNo in the radio button value field, and once again, use the PictureNo to look up information in the database.

Comment: I've updated my second servlet. At the moment it'll fetch the right folder name, but it won't run the second statement.

Comment: Is there an error message? Can you debug it and step through?  What happens?   Is it maybe that there are no matching records found?